# How do you execture the subdivide function on the multiresolution modifier in python?

Tags: python, multiresolution

I have add the MULTIRES modifier to an object in Python and would like to trigger the "subdivide" function. Since in Python you define a modifier like so:

```
obj.modifiers.new(type='MULTIRES', name="test")
obj.modifiers['test'].subdivision_type = 'CATMULL_CLARK'
```

How do I call the subdivide function? The Python info window is not helping neither it just says: (`bpy.ops.object.multires_subdivide(modifier="test")`).

And all my current attempts throw errors:

- `bpy.ops.object.multires_subdivide(modifier="test")`
- `obj.modifiers['test'].multires_subdivide(modifier="test")`
- `obj.modifiers['test'].multires_subdivide()`
- `obj.modifiers['test'].subdivide()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you see in [API](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.78a/bpy.ops.object.html?highlight=multires_subdivide#bpy.ops.object.multires_subdivide)

> bpy.ops.object.multires_subdivide(modifier="") Add a new level of
>   subdivision

you can test this:

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='MULTIRES')
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Multires"].name = "A"
bpy.context.object.modifiers["A"].subdivision_type = 'CATMULL_CLARK'
bpy.ops.object.multires_subdivide(modifier="A")
```